# php - How to access post variables ($_POST is empty)

Tags: php, json, post

I'm working on a system and currently try to implement a script that another (external) system can post to some data so I can store them.
I have no control over the external system - I can just trigger it to post data to my system, giving it my script's url.

Looking at firebug when the post happens, I can see the data posted, something that looks like this:[image]

or (urldecoded)

```
content={"sex":"male","person":{"name":["chris"],"mbox":["mailto:name.lastename@gmail.com"]}}  
&Content-Type=application/json  
&auth=DDE233H76BGN
```

My problem is that when trying to get these parameters in my script, $_POST (and $_REQUEST) is always empty!
I've tried `var_dump($_POST)` or `echo file_get_contents("php://input");`, but I don't see any contents.

What am I missing here?
I don't know if response/request headers are needed to get something out of it, I show them here just in case
[image]

**Edit:**
My script now consists of a single line of code, like:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("php://input");
?>
```

both of them give me absolutelly nothing :s

Comment: Please show us the PHP script this is being posted to.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for replying. I'm just doing `var_dump($_REQUEST);` or `echo file_get_contents("php://input");`. Just one line of code.

Comment: What's the code that creates the request? The content type should be a header, not part of the post data.

Comment: @Arjan I have no access or control over the code that creates the request. It just sends me a param named Content-type and i need to store it

Answer (score 1):

The data should be accessed using `$arr= json_decode($_POST['content']);` ... but you have another problem here.

**A detail is missing:**

... how can firebug can show you the content of a $_POST that is sent from an external system to your website ( aka: the request does not go through your browser, but probably through an CURL request originating from the external server ). Obviously, I don't get something here.

What I see is a POST request sent from your browser ( in javascript ), made by your website.
Your question miss a crucial detail, I'm just not sure what it is.

**Hint:**

Try to put an `echo 'test';` just before your var_dump, I have the feeling that you may not be debugging the page that is really called by the Ajax POST request that we see in Firebug. A little routing problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at RFC 1945 to see what "parameter" is

```
parameter      = attribute "=" value
attribute      = token
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or tspecials>
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                    (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
```

So i suppose "Content-Type=application/json" is not a valid part of POST because "-" is not of CTLs

Comment: `any CHAR except CTLs` means to me that any character that is not in CTL is allowed, so the `-` should be fine too.

Comment: @Ziumin Thanks a lot for bothering with my question. You are absolutelly right, but that was just a typo, coz i just edited the post params in the image to leave only 2-3 of them so it is clearer to you what is happening (in real there are more than 10 parameters, it would not be easy to read).
You can check the upadated question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking at the raw POST data variable:

`echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;`